# List<String> not removing item

Tags: c#, json, list

I'm writing a call tracking application, which hit's a push server and gets a JSON result set of the calls that have come in. Within the JSON object, there is an array of Keys that contains the logID for each call.

When a new call comes in, I create a new tab page and associate a call object with the tab pages tag property. Then I check if a call has been dispositioned, if it has the push server removes the logID from the Keys array. Then I'm comparing the logIds in the Keys array with the logIds for each call object, that is associated with each open tabs.

When run my code it removes the logID from the _psKeys List, but then add's it back on the next iteration. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
        var jsonResult = _pushServer.GetWebRequest(_pushServer.GetNewCallUrl(_locationID, _clientID));
        var jsonObject = _pushServer.GetJsonObject(jsonResult);

        _tabKeys.Clear();
        _psKeys.Clear();

        // Load the tabKeys with all the keys for the open tabs.
        foreach (TabPage tab in newCallTabControl.TabPages)
        {
            Call call = (Call)tab.Tag;
            _tabKeys.Add(call.LogID);                
        }

        // Load the Push Server Keys
        foreach (string key in jsonObject.keys)
        {
            _psKeys.Add(key);                
        }

        // Iterate over the keys and compare
        foreach (string tabKey in _tabKeys)
        {
            foreach (string psKey in _psKeys)
            {
                if (! _tabKeys.Contains(psKey))
                {
                    // Remove the tab
                    foreach (TabPage tabPage in newCallTabControl.TabPages)
                    {
                        Call tabCallObject = (Call)tabPage.Tag;
                        if (tabCallObject.LogID == tabKey)
                        {
                            newCallTabControl.TabPages.Remove(tabPage);                        
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }                
        }
```

Comment: this would be better on the codereview stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't be removing items from a list you are enumerating.  I'd simply not add them in the first place....

```
    var jsonResult = _pushServer.GetWebRequest(_pushServer.GetNewCallUrl(_locationID, _clientID));
    var jsonObject = _pushServer.GetJsonObject(jsonResult);

    _tabKeys.Clear();
    _psKeys.Clear();
// Load the Push Server Keys
    foreach (string key in jsonObject.keys)
    {
        _psKeys.Add(key);                
    }
    var tabsToRemove = new List<TabPage>();
// Load the tabKeys with all the keys for the open tabs.
    foreach (TabPage tab in newCallTabControl.TabPages)
    {
        Call call = (Call)tab.Tag;
        if(_psKeys.Contains(call.LogID)
        {               
          _tabKeys.Add(call.LogID); 
        }               
        else
        {
          tabsToRemove.Add(tab)
        }
    }
    tabsToRemove.ForEach(t => newCallTabControl.TabPages.Remove(t));
```

or if you don't need the lists...

```
var tabsToRemove = newCallTabControl.TabPages
          .Where(tab => !jsonObject.keys.Contains(((Call)tab.tag).LogID))
          .ToList();
tabsToRemove.ForEach(t => newCallTabControl.TabPages.Remove(t));
```

Comment: What should I use to hold the logId's and compare them? Would an Array be a better option?

Comment: Even if I remove the line that removes the item from the _tabKeys list, the list are cleared and auto populated from the JSON results, and provide the same results.

Comment: I just edited it a bit.   Its hard to know from the context what happening.   It seems a bit convoluted to me

Comment: You rock! Thanks man that worked like a charm...Just had to create the Call object outside the if statement.

Comment: I like the second option, but it doesn't work. No Where method on TabPage?

Comment: ah, dang, can't use Linq on it :/  nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to get the data you need to operate on, then do the operations separately:

```
var tabKeysToRemove = _tabKeys.Where(t => !_psKeys.Contains(t)).ToList();
foreach (var tabKey in tabKeysToRemove)
{
    _tabKeys.Remove(tabKey);
    var tabsToRemove = newCallTabControl.TabPages
        .Where(tp => ((Call)tp.Tag).logID == tabKey).ToList();
    tabsToRemove.forEach(t => newCallTabControl.TabPages.Remove(t));
}
```

Comment: That won't work as is.  Because of the lazy nature of LINQ you're still iterating over _tabKeys while you remove items from it.  You need a `.ToList()` call at the end of each of your LINQ chains to decouple the removal lists from the original ones.

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying a couple of collections that you're iterating over.  That's never a good idea.

Also, in terms of the logic of your loops you don't seem to be doing anyting with the iteration over _psKeys.  Should it be something like:

```
foreach (string tabKey in _tabKeys)        
{            
    if (! _psKeys.Contains(tabKey))
    {
        //Remove the tab
        //...
    }
}
```